# Doctrine 2 - Expr class usage

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an Entity Repository that contains the following method:

```
<?php
namespace Brs\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


class UserRepository extends EntityRepository

{
    public function findMentors(){
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb ->select('u')
            ->from('BrsUserBundle:User', 'u')
            ->where('u.mentor = 1');

        return $qb;
    }
}
```

Now I want to customize this query further by concatenating the fname and lname fields from the User entity and assign an alias. In MySql the query would be:

```
SELECT *,concat(fname,' ',lname) as name FROM table;
```

That exactly what I want.

Now using Doctrine 2's Query Builder I need to implement this.
I have referred to the [Expr Class](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) and I can see the concat() method that I can use.

I just can't seem to get the syntax correct and struggle to understand how to implement this from their examples.

So could any one please give me an example on how to create the above query in Query Builder using the Expr Class?

Better still help me understand how the Expr Class is used in different instances so i can understand this logically and syntactically.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 1):

i know this is not exactly the answer to your question

but i would rather edit your user class and add a fullname property, sth like

```
private $fullName;


public function getFullName(){
   return $this->getFirstName()." ".$this->getLastName();
}
```

i think this is more straight forward and oo

Comment: Even though you have not answered my question directly, You have solved my problem with your suggestion. Thank you, I never thought of that :-)